# Is it possible to avoid Wizz Air's administration fee?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, fees-and-charges, wizz-air

Wizz Air charges an [EUR 8 administration fee](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/prices-discounts/all-services-fees#/) on all tickets booked online, via its mobile app, or via a call center. Its fares are low enough that this is often a substantial component of the final price paid.

Is there any way to book tickets *without* paying this fee, (possibly, for example, at a physical sales office or with a travel agent)?

An ideal answer will refer to an actual experience booking a ticket without paying this fee, rather than the theoretical possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WizzAir's website](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/booking-information/how-to-book#/) says you can book via travel agents or at the airport ticket counter. Also lists 10€ as the call center fee.

But being an LCC, they probably don't pay travel agent commissions, so a travel agent would likely charge you a handling fee.

The webpage you cite, mentions that there may be additional fees charged by the handing agent at airports as well.  If you live at WizzAir's hubs, you would likely be dealing with WizzAir staff not a handling agent, but at destination airports, you will probably be dealing with handling agents.