# Anyone know what a Wizzair System surcharge is?

Tags: fees-and-charges, wizz-air

Looks like it is a charge for using their automated systems. This seems pretty strange since I thought that was what the administration charge is for.
[image]
https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/prices-discounts/all-services-fees

Comment: Could it also be a fee that applies when the booking is made through a 3rd party booking sites like Kayak or so?

Comment: For me they add it even in incognito mode, even in the app

Answer (score 12):

One important addition to Xnero's answer: the System surcharge fee doesn't apply in case you book through the Wizz mobile app. (Just tried it.)

Comment: This fee is added when their system thinks you are a bot and detects your "non-standard" behaviour in the browser. It can also happen when you use an ad blocker. As @florien said, booking through the Wizz mobie app does not involve this fee (as well just confirmed).

Answer (score 10):

This fee applies to all bookings no matter if it’s online or through a call centre. They are a low-cost carrier so they make money out of such fees.

This is made so the cost of the ticket seems cheap but actually isn’t.

For example a bag can cost more than the flight, it’s €30 per person if you don’t check-in online but at the airport and €15 for a call centre request, something which should be standard especially if you just have a question.

You almost have no choice to pay this fee.

From this Travel.SE question [Is it possible to avoid Wizz Air's administration fee?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85264/is-it-possible-to-avoid-wizz-airs-administration-fee):

> WizzAir's website says you can book via travel agents or at the airport ticket counter. Also lists 10€ as the call center fee.
>
> But being an LCC, they probably don't pay travel agent commissions, so a travel agent would likely charge you a handling fee.
>
> The webpage you cite, mentions that there may be additional fees charged by the handing agent at airports as well. If you live at WizzAir's hubs, you would likely be dealing with WizzAir staff not a handling agent, but at destination airports, you will probably be dealing with handling agents.

Comment: Are fees in Europe like fees in the US where there has to be a way to avoid paying them in order for them to be called a fee? In the US, some of the ULCCs have extra fees that one can avoid by driving to the airport and actually paying for the ticket there at the counter, for instance.

Comment: @cbw Not in general regarding the exact use of the word 'fee', but there are regulations against deceptive advertisements. An airline can't post 'Paris-London for €1.99" on a billboard if the only real option to get the flight is to pay anything on top of €1.99.

Comment: isn't this fee included in the fare quoted in the search results?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, that _should_ be the law anywhere, but in USA, it is standard practice to advertise a price and then tack on a LIST of fees, surcharges, and taxes.  Usually it doesn't happen with airfares, but definitely with other things.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it has something to do with 3rd parties. I have searched for a particular flight using Skyscanner and then they have sent me to the Wizzair site. I saw this surcharge before the end of the booking.

I opened a new browser in incognito mode and I searched for the same flight directly on Wizzair (no more 3rd parties this time). Afterwards, the surcharge did not apply again anymore.

Comment: I have to confirm tha same. Just happend to me. Sneaky £13 was added to the final price under "system surcharge". I had Kayak site opened in another tab but I did not use the forwarding from there. I started from afresh from WizzAir main page. But still they somehow new. Shared cookies? Anyway. Re-doing the booking in another browser where I did not use Kayak or Skyscanner helped. No incognito mode needed. I used my usuall WizzAir account in both attempts, makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

"
This fee is added when their system thinks you are a bot and detects your "non-standard" behavior in the browser. It can also happen when you use an ad blocker. "
Yes, I changed browser and the fee dissapeared.
Thank you.

Note: in app also I had this fee.

Comment: That's ridiculous! Can you share the source? I wonder how can it comply with the UE rules...